# How to have a new instance of a view when a new item is created (swiftui)?

Tags: swiftui, directory

I was not sure how to word the question. I am making a simple notes app and am using a three column view. I want the user to create a new folder which is initially empty but they can add notes to it. My problem is that every folder goes to the same notes. If a new note is created in one folder, you see it in all the others.

Example (yes I know both folders are generically set to "New Folder", I'm working on trying to let the user set names):

[image]

[image]

I know the general problem is that when a new folder is created, they all go to the "NoteView". But I want a newly created folder to go to a different VERSION of the "NoteView" that is initially empty. Like you see in any Notes app, I want each folders' notes to be different, not them all referencing the same notes.

My code is below. Sidebar is where the folders are displayed. NoteView is where the corresponding notes are supposed to be displayed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Sidebar()
            Text("No folder selected")
            Text("No note selected")
           
        }
    }
}

struct Sidebar: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Folder.folderName, ascending: true)])
    var folders: FetchedResults<Folder>
    
    @State private var selectedFoldersIds: Set<Folder.ID> = []
    
    private var selectedFolder: Folder?{
        guard let selectedFolderId = selectedFoldersIds.first,
              let selectedFolder = folders.filter ({$0.id == selectedFolderId}).first else{
                  return nil
              }
        return selectedFolder
    }
    var body: some View {
        List(folders, selection: $selectedFoldersIds){folder in
            NavigationLink(folder.folderName, destination:NoteView()) //each folder created navigates to NoteView() which stores all created notes. But I want each folder to have empty notes until one is added. 
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .onDeleteCommand(perform: deleteSelectedFolders)
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: createFolder){
                    Label("Create Quick Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: deleteSelectedFolders){
                    Label("Delete note", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
        }
      
    
}
    
    private func createFolder(){
         createFolder(name: "New Folder")
        
    }
    private func createFolder(name: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let folder = Folder(context: viewContext)
            folder.folderId = UUID()
            folder.folderName = name
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteSelectedFolders(){
        withAnimation{
            let selectedFolders = folders.filter {selectedFoldersIds.contains($0.id)}
            deleteFolders(folders: selectedFolders)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteFolders(folders: [Folder]){
        viewContext.perform{ folders.forEach(viewContext.delete)}
    }
}

struct NoteView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.name, ascending: true)])
    var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
    
    @State private var selectedNotesIds: Set<Note.ID> = []
    
    private var selectedNote: Note?{
        guard let selectedNoteId = selectedNotesIds.first,
              let selectedNote = notes.filter ({$0.id == selectedNoteId}).first else{
                  return nil
              }
        return selectedNote
    }
    var body: some View {
        List(notes, selection: $selectedNotesIds){ note in
            NavigationLink(note.name, destination: NoteEditor(note: note ))
        }
      
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: createNote){
                    Label("Create Quick Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: deleteSelectedNotes){
                    Label("Delete note", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
            
        }
         
  
        
      
    }
    
    private func createNote(){
         createNote(name: "New note", text: "")
        
    }
    private func createNote(name: String, text: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let note = Note(context: viewContext)
            note.id = UUID()
            note.name = name
            note.text = text
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteSelectedNotes(){
        withAnimation{
            let selectedNotes = notes.filter {selectedNotesIds.contains($0.id)}
            deleteNotes(notes: selectedNotes)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteNotes(notes: [Note]){
        viewContext.perform{ notes.forEach(viewContext.delete)}
    }
}
```

Comment: in `NoteView` you fetch all notes and display them. The view doesn't know which folder has been selected and you don't filter notes by folder. So it's clear it always shows all of them ... 

you should pass the selected folder to the subview (as @ObservedObject) and then only show this folder's notes.  If there is a one-to-may relationship from folder to notes you won't even need another @FetchRequest. Just set up an array of all children in the model and use selectedFolder.notesArray.

Comment: You are creating new notes that are not linked to any folder. You don't do that in your view, but in your model. Inside the `Folder` type (in Core Data you have relationships), add a variable that gathers all notes for that specific folder: like `var notes = [Note]()` if it was a struct. Then, one view presents all notes for that folder (`List(folder.notes)`), and another view presents the single note.

Comment: Any specific examples? It sounds great but I'm new to this so it's a bit difficult to visualize when I'm still trying to grasp the concepts.

Comment: this might me a good demo project: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui/53

Comment: I tried @ObservedObject var folder: Folder in my NoteView. The destination of the Sidebar is NoteView(folder: folder), but it still shows the same notes in each folder.